# Redux form "submiting" value not goes true on form submit

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-redux-form

When I am submiting the form submitSucceeded props goes true, pristine is also working fine but submitting props not change on submit form. I have attached related code. Please suggest me how I can fix this issue.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import FileInput from '../FileInput'

import 'react-widgets/dist/css/react-widgets.css';
import './reactForm.css';

const EditForm = (props) => {
const { handleSubmit, submitSucceeded, pristine, submitting, owners,      cities, compound, avatarUrl, changeAvatar } = props;
return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <div className="row padding-20-0">
      <div className="col-md-4">
        <div className="box-upfile cursor" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${avatarUrl})`}} >
          <div className="editImgComp" >
            <i className="sprite-icon icon-030" onClick={()=>{changeAvatar(null); props.change('avatar', null)}}/>
            <label html="imageBrowse">
              <FileInput 
                onDone={(file)=> {changeAvatar(file.file); props.change("avatar", file.file)}}
                type="file" className="hidden" id="imageBrowse"/>
              <i className="sprite-icon icon-031"/>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="row">
      <div className="text-right col-xs-6">
        {
          submitSucceeded ?
            <button type="button" className="btn ls-btn-red cursor" disabled={pristine || submitting || submitSucceeded}>
              <i className='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i> Saving
            </button>
            :
            <button type="submit" className="btn ls-btn-red cursor" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={handleSubmit} >Save</button>
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
 )
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'compoundForm'  // a unique identifier for this form
})(EditForm)
```

Container:-

```
handleSubmit(data) {
    this.props.dispatch(compoundSave(data));
}
```

Action:-

```
export function compoundSave(data) {
  const id = data.id;
  const config = {
   method: 'put', 
   body: JSON.stringify({compound: data}),
 };
 return callApi('/v1/compounds/'+id, {}, config, compoundSaveRequest, compoundSaveSuccess, compoundSaveFailure);
}
```

Call Api method:-

```
`export function callApi(path, params, config, request, onRequestSuccess, onRequestFailure) {
  const API_ROOT = 'http://api.dev.leasing.clicksandbox.com:8080';
  const idToken = localStorage.getItem('id_token');

  let url = API_ROOT+path;
  url = buildUrlWithQueryString(url, params);

  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(request);

    return fetch(url, config)
      .then(checkStatus)
      .then(parseJSON)
      .then((json) => {
        if (!json.success) {   // (response.status < 200 || response.status > 300)
         json.error &&
         Toastr.error(json.error);
         dispatch(onRequestFailure(json));
       } else {
         json.message &&
         Toastr.success(json.message);
         dispatch(onRequestSuccess(json));
       }
     }).catch((error) => {
         const exceptionMessage = {
           success: false,
           error: "Something went wrong!"
         }
        dispatch(onRequestFailure(exceptionMessage));
       });
 };
```

}`

Please let me know if I need to explain more.

Comment: The `submitting` prop only functions if your `onSubmit` is asynchronous (i.e. returns a `Promise`). Is that the case?

Comment: Thank you for reply, But I am not getting you. 
Let me brief more :- I dont have added any validation async or sync. But I have checked the redux-form official doc and in both example submitting is working. 
SyncValidatin
http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/examples/syncValidation/
asyncvalidation
http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/examples/asyncValidation/

Comment: Please show your `onSubmit` function, otherwise we'll not be able to help.

Comment: @gustavohenke I have just update the code.

Comment: @AnujDhanju did u ever figure this one out? Same problem

Answer (score 2):

For any one else arriving here a year later like me looking for answers, and without seeing the Container code... i can infer that the problem is that you defined the method *handleSubmit* in the Container and send it as a prop to *EditForm*. The problem with that is that a Component that has the *reduxForm()* HOC applied, in this case *EditForm*, will generate its own *handleSubmit* prop, and therefore a conflict arises, leading to wrong behaviour of the form when submitting. 
In order to fix the issue, you should have send the prop to EditForm with a different name say

```
<EditForm onSubmit={this.onSubmit} />
```

And then inside the EditForm component use it like:

...

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
```

That way the prop *submitting* of the reduxForm component will work if the submit handler returns a promise.

Answer (score 1):

you should call `handleSubmit()` method with handler passed to component :

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.props.onSubmit)}>
```